# How to disable the first page of pageadapter be displayed automatically?

Tags: java, android, fragment

I found even if I dont invoke FragmentPageAdaper.setCurrentItem(0), the first page in adapter displays all the same.

For now, I created a empty page instead, to be displayed as the first page. It works, but I still wonder if there's a way to disable the first page be displayed automatically when activity's created.
ps. Sorry for my English.

Comment: you don't want to display first page, so what do you want to do?

Comment: leave the place empty, until I need to display one of the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the initial visibility state of the view pager as `VIEW.GONE` using:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

and when condition meet, you change the visibility:

```
yourViewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: yeah, it's another solution I have tried. I just wonder if there is a real 'manual mode' in pagerAdapter view.